# Technical user break the security in JSP pages

Tags: java, html, security, jsp, frameworks

I have implemented field base security in JSP pages.

If the field is read only to the user, I put the attribute **readonly="true"** ;

But some users are technical, and they know about firebug in Firefox or related tools, using these tools, they remove read-only attribute from dom and change the value of field.

How can I control this? or any other mechanism ?

Comment: Server side validation?

Comment: Can you put some code of JSP ? as @g.d.d.c said - Server side validation would be best. The concept is called Entitlement- go through What are Entitlement section of this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12890_01/ales/docs32/secintro/entitlements.html)

Comment: Generally, if you don’t want some parameter to be manipulated, don’t make that parameter available for the user. What kind of information do you not want to be editable?

Comment: How can you rely on client to verify anything? The least is to have a token on a server as well and check for equality on sensible operations, like deletion. In the end, JSF is a framework, *capable* of doing what you want with ease. So why not follow that road?

Comment: hmmm... Client requirement not to use JSF @skuntsel any other way?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do anything against that users modify the document you served. Anything you send to the client is under their control and out of your control.

But there are only some techniques that you can do to avoid or detect such parameter tampering:

- **Avoidance**: The less parameters you make to the client available, the less parameters can be tampered. If you don’t want a certain parameter to be changed (probably any hidden form field), don’t send it to the client but keep it on the server side. You could store these parameters in some kind of container inside the client’s session and associate it with the current form. The only information that is then sent to the client is a random identifier of the container that references the server side stored parameters.
- **Detection:** You can use cryptographic hash functions like [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) to verify that the data that is returned by the client is identical to the data that was sent to it. But be aware that this still allows [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).